# Field Formulas: Count Members Except Status Blacklist

Tags: formula, formula-field, standard-objects, campaign, campaign-member

I am customizing our Campaign page and adding a field called "Total Participants". I want to only count Campaign Members whose status is not equal to "No Show", "Not Attending". This is simple to do in a report, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into a formula.

I found this [Salesforce forum post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gqgNAAQ), but from my understanding it would require creating a new report for each Campaign.

The best I can come up with is:

```
// LEN(GETRECORDIDS()) gets total number of records from a certain object
// `Self` is wrong but I'm not sure how to reference the current object's sub-objects

LEN(GETRECORDIDS((
Self.CampaignMember.Status != "Not Attending") && (Self.CampaignMember.Status != "No Show")
))
```

I'm betting this is far off base, but I'm not sure what direction to take this while keeping to the confines of a formula field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new `Rollup Summary` field on `Campaign`.
2. Select `Summarized Object` > `Campaign Members`.
3. Select `Roll-Up Type` > `COUNT`.
4. Select `Filter Criteria` > `Only records meeting certain criteria should be included in the calculation`.
5. Select `Field` > `Status`.
6. Select `Operator` > `not equal to`.
7. Use the lookup dialog to select the picklist options to ignore.

Comment: does rollup summary fields work for lookup relation? As relation between Campaign and Campaign Member is lookup not master detail.

Comment: @Tara Take a look for yourself in the UI, it is available. You can install [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to work with lookups when OOB Rollup Summary Fields are not available.

Comment: @Tara -- You pointed out something odd - the Setup | Customize | Campaign Member | Fields does indeed show `Campaign` as a Lookup relationship but Adrian is right in that RSF can be done from Campaign -> CM. This relationship is a cascade delete relationship which is an indicator for master-detail

Comment: @crop1645 Yeah I just assumed it was M/D when I was able to create RSF. Pretty weird behavior. It is also a required lookup.

Comment: I suspect this is a legacy from some long ago SFDC - Winter '88 or the like